# Retrieve image from BLOB - Mysql Xamarin - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, blob

Converting Image to Blob: (Working well)

```
            Stream fs = _mediaFile.GetStream();
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

Converting Blob to Image: (Not working, why?)
Fetching from MySQL reader: **rd1[2]**

```
                bytes = (byte[])rd1[2];
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                resultImage1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);
```

Comment: have you compared the actual bytes being written in the first block to the bytes being read back in the 2nd block?  Have you verified that the bytes read are actually valid image data?

Comment: I’m stuck still on this. Kindly help me dear Jason

Comment: you didn't respond to any of the questions I asked you